# How to solve Check the render method of App in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm getting this error **Check the render method of `App`.**, i don't know why this is happening. i have tried to resolve this issue and search on different platforms but i can't get any solution to this.

here's **App.js** file

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home } from "./Home";
import { ShoesBrandLaunch } from "./ShoesBrandLaunch";
import { ShoeLaunch } from "./ShoeLaunch";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/nike" element={<ShoesBrandLaunch />}>
          <Route path=":slug" element={<ShoeLaunch />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

here's the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qsevgk?file=src/index.js) for the complete app

Comment: I got the error to go away when I changed `Routes` to `Switch`

Comment: Have a look https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-trvzq1?file=src%2FApp.js. Your app is broken at so many levels. You must follow the documentation for the basics, do some research on what you use and how you use and then only post a question.

Answer (score 0):

The `Routes` named export is no longer how you do routing, you want to use a `Switch` instead, for example:

```
       <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
```

I believe your code might be for version 4 of React Router. You're also missing a Link import in Home.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Routes, use Switch. Also wrap the whole thing in a BrowserRouter That's the one I always use and it works. So like this:

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home } from "./Home";
import { ShoesBrandLaunch } from "./ShoesBrandLaunch";
import { ShoeLaunch } from "./ShoeLaunch";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/nike" element={<ShoesBrandLaunch />}>
        <Route path=":slug" element={<ShoeLaunch />} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: OP has a BrowserRouter in index.js, so that part was working at least :)

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that.